# Get screen position of "div" element

Tags: python

Im trying to create a webscraper with Python.
I want to avoid selenium, so I think the best way to simulate a user is to move the mouse to specific coordinates and simulate a mouseclick.

```
import mouse 
mouse.move("500", "500")
mouse.left_click()
```

But for this way I need to find the coordinates for the div-element I want to click.
Is there a possibility without selenium?

Comment: _avoid selenium_: Why tagging _Selenium_?

Comment: I'm not saying it's not possible, but I doubt it. What if the browser window moves or changes its size? You could turn your program into a ***screen*** scraper but that seems like a lot of hard work for nothing. ***Why*** do you want to avoid something that already solves this problem?

Comment: Because some platforms are detecting selenium and banning the profile you are using

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks